# How to query / retrieve keywords using YouTube Data API (v3)

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm currently in the process of migrating from an obsolete youtube gdata API to V3. One of the things I'm looking for is :

1. Search videos using a filter

   I used to run something like this

   https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/lyndapodcast/uploads?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=1&query=sample_keyword

Will this V3 request will be equivalent using "q" parameter ?

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=sample_keyword&channelId=UCUtTNe0bVxvk8exLBKkvCNg&maxResults=50&key={my_key}&maxResults=2
```

2. Is there a way to retrieve "keywords" as part of the result ? gdata API didn't allow it earlier, only way was to scrape the html page and look for keywords metadata.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

-Thanks,

Shamik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, except for the different maxResults value you're using.
2. You can get tags only if you own the videos. Otherwise scrape the keywords metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. One last question, right now I'm using channelId to retrieve videos for a specific user. Is it possible to use the channel name instead. For e.g. in old API, I could simply specify "lyndapodcast" in the url but now I've to provide the id which in this case is  "UCUtTNe0bVxvk8exLBKkvCNg".

Comment: Yes you can take the channel name and make a call to the channel endpoint to get the ID for the channel. See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Comment: @john10 Is it possible to query multiple channel ids in one API request, or is a separate API request per channel id required?

Comment: Did you click the link? It states "The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of the YouTube channel ID(s) for the resource(s) that are being retrieved. In a channel resource, the id property specifies the channel's YouTube channel ID."

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core to get keywords for youtube videos.